# Django urldecode in template file

Tags: python, django, django-templates

is there any way do the `urldecode` in Django template file?

Just opposite to [urlencode](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#urlencode) or [escape](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#escape)

I want to convert `app%20llc` to `app llc`

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that in the template?  Shouldn't your view be providing the template with perfect data to begin with?

Comment: sure! because i want to do it in a for loop to print table rows in template page

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could create a simple [custom filter](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) around [urllib.unquote](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#utility-functions)

For instance:

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter
from urllib import unquote

@stringfilter
def unquote_raw(value):
    return unquote(value)
```

and now you can have this in your django template file:

```
{{ raw|unquote_raw }}
```

Comment: i want to do it is template file not in view

Comment: are you want me do some thing like this http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/ ?

Comment: thanks it is, but this unquote is not unescaping `&amp;` to `&`

Comment: From the urllib.unquote() docs: "Replace %xx escapes by their single-character equivalent."

Answer (score 10):

you have to write something like this instead of the previous answer otherwise you will get a maximum recursion depth

```
from urllib import unquote
from django.template.defaultfilters import register
from urllib.parse import unquote #python3

@register.filter
def unquote_new(value):
    return unquote(value)
```

> {{ raw|unquote_new }}