# Django adds %2f in place of the / in the template for an image field

Tags: django, django-templates

I am having a few issues with a django template with a mimetype="text/plain".

Firstly the s3 part of url is rendering with the :80 on the end and then the actual image url is rendering with '%2f' in replace of each slash.

```
object.image.url
```

I have tried safe and other custom tags to replace the '%2f' and it just wont work

```
#what I have
http://blahblah.s3.amazonaws.com:80/navigation%2Fprimary%2Fimage.jpg

#what I want
http://blahblah.s3.amazonaws.com/navigation/primary/image.jpg
```

The custom tag I have tried along side safe is:

```
import re 
from django import template

register = template.Library()

def reslash (value): 
    return value.replace('%2f', '/')


register.filter('reslash', reslash)
```

used like this:

```
{{ object.image.url|reslash }}
```

But it doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: Where is this url coming from? How are you outputting it in the template?

Comment: {{ object.image.url|safe }} should output the URL without modification - see http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#safe

Comment: @Daniel Roseman the url is coming from a loop of navigation objects, each of which have an image field, which uploads to s3 on save. So I can easily loop through and output the title, but for some reason with the |safe it still does the same. It may be because I am outputting to text/css or text/plan.

Comment: Did you try [unquote](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5229088/538471)?

Answer (score 0):

Django automatically html escapes all variables in templates. In order to insert the value of a variable without escaping you should use the `safe` filter to tell django the value does not need to be auto-escaped like so:

```
{{ object.image.url|safe }}
```